# How to send a money order for a Canada visa application?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, vfs-global, visitor

I was told to send a 21.70 USD money order for a fee to the Canada Visa Application Center. I tried sending a money order from Walmart but now I am having some issues. I called Walmart and they told me to contact MoneyGram and they said the checks were outstanding, they weren't sent. I learned from this site that we can use USPS for this. Can someone tell me the process please? It's urgent.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Khushi, welcome to TSE. What "issues" specifically are you having?

Comment: We can't tell where the problem is. Was the money order actually sent by you to VAC? Did the VAC receive the money order? Has the money order been cashed by the VAC?